# Cursor blinking is VERY slow and Settings doesn't help

Tags: 20.04, settings, cursor

It seems that my Ubuntu 20.04 has slowed down the cursor blinking. Even if I go to Settings → *Universal Access* → *Cursor Blinking* and change the *Speed*, it doesn't help at all. I even tried switching cursor blinking off and on, to "reset" it. Didn't help. It's very unpractical to have to wait for a second or more before you know where you are in a text editor!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right to be frustrated. The Settings → *Universal Access* → *Cursor Blinking* → *Speed* option works counter-intuitively. The option should have been named as "time delay" or something, instead of *Speed*, since what the parameter changes is the delay between consecutive blinks.

So you have to actually reduce the *Speed*, by dragging the slider to the left, in order to speed up the blinking.

[image: Cursor Blinking Speed option]

Comment: Yes. THAT works! Although I had to restart Ubuntu AND turn Cursor Blinking off and on...

Comment: @HenrikR. Hmmm. I am not able to replicate this, but if you ever come across another setting that doesn't get applied, first try restarting the shell (pressing `Alt`+`F2`, typing `r` and pressing `Enter`), instead of rebooting. This is especially recommended when installing an extension, or when something is misbehaving, and can save you a bit of time, since all your applications will remain open, as opposed to rebooting.

Comment: I have just tried this out, and indeed I can observe the setting applied on the fly — for Gedit and for the terminal; I change the slider, focus the other window, and can see the new behavior right away. (Ubuntu 20.04.1, Gnome v 3.36.8 Gnome shell v 3.36.4)